# Python TCP server/client for transferring files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I was trying to make a TCP server/client in order to transfer files between the two. My code looks like this (its messy) for now. When sending a GET command I want to receive a file from the server which works but only if I ^C to close the client (the file is created but nothing is written in it until I close the client).  When I send a SEND command to get a file from the server (machine running the server) it works but just because I shutdown the socket after that. I want to keep the socket connected after sending the file.

Here is the code that is used for this:

server.py

```
            elif msg[:4] == 'file':
                client_command = msg[5:9]

                if client_command == 'GET ':
                    file_name = msg[9:]

                    f = open(file_name, "rb")
                    l = f.read(self.BUFF_SIZE)

                    while(l):
                        self.send_info(l)
                        l = f.read(self.BUFF_SIZE)

                    f.close()

                elif client_command == 'SEND':
                    file_name = msg[10:]

                    f = open(file_name, "wb")
                    l = self.recv_info()

                    while(l):
                        f.write(l)
                        l = self.recv_info()

                    f.close()

def send_info(self, msg):
        info = bytes(msg)
        send = self.client_socket.sendall(info)

        return send

def recv_info(self):
        recv = self.client_socket.recv(self.BUFF_SIZE)

        return recv
```

client.py

```
    answer = input()

    elif answer[:4] == 'file':
        s.send(answer.encode('iso-8859-1'))

        command = answer[5:9]

        if command == 'GET ': 
            fileName = answer[9:]

            f = open(fileName, 'wb')
            l = s.recv(2048)

            while(l):
                f.write(l)
                l = s.recv(2048)
                
            f.close()

        elif command == 'SEND':
            fileName = answer[10:]

            f = open(fileName, 'rb')
            l = f.read(2048)

            while (l):
                s.send(l)
                l = f.read(2048)
            
            f.close()
            s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```

I will change the way I'm taking care of the filename and move away from slicing once I'm sure the transferring works.

I probably just don't understand how the transfer should be made but if anyone could correct my code or explain how it should be tin order to be functional. I just want to be able to send and transfer files without the socket closing (shutdown) so that I don't have to reconnect the client after every command and without having to close the client to finish transferring a file. I can add more of the code if need be.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the file is being buffered. If you want to enforce the file will be written right after you have received, you can use the `flush` method:

```py
f = open(fileName, 'wb')
l = s.recv(2048)

while(l):
  f.write(l)
  l = s.recv(2048)
f.flush()                
f.close()
```

Note: I **Highly suggest** you use the `with` statement, to ensure the file is always closed:

```py
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
  l = s.recv(2048)
  while(l):
    f.write(l)
    l = s.recv(2048)
  f.flush()
```

Comment: I tried what you answered and now both commands just create the file on the other machine but the contents are written when I close the client, do you have any idea of how I can fix that ? (I also removed the s.shutdown() call in client.py during testing)

Comment: I changed the way I handled the connections and now the SEND command works but the GET command is stuck on this line:  l = s.recv(2048)      in the while loop. Do you have any idea why that is ?

Comment: I know it might be a bit late, but if the problem persists, could you update the question with the new code? Also, if the server is stuck on the `s.recv` method it might be because the client stopped sending any information but the connection was not closed (the method is locking).